# Set up multiple VPN's with a static ip with PPTP with only 1 vpn-login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, pptp, point-to-point-protocol

I have a VPS with Ubuntu 12.04 x64 and i need to connect 118 VPN's to interfaces with (pon vpnname). I've made a script that creates them all, the problem is that no interface will have a unique local IP Address, i think it's because of the speed of the script because when i run it slower it works better (but still not everything unique).. I've tried and searched everything for 5 hours with another programmer on a row and we couldn't find anything good. I just need to give all the vpn hostnames different static ip's and my problem is solved but i can't get it to work , even not with the config files.

Thanks in advance guys !

Answer (score 0):

what we used previously seems similiar to what you need:

Openvpn Server which gets connected by a few 100 clients (they connected via GPRS, every client had its own cert, hostname and own IP.
our DNS Server updated the IPs of the hostnames (custom-up.sh and custom-down.sh scripts) and you were able to f.e. ping every client on his hostname.

we had a DNS zone for the link hostname-"VPN ip"